# How to remove ggplot area border?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**EDIT:**  THIS ISN'T A THEME ISSUE, THIS IS A FUNCTION PROBLEM.

Please refer to the second code block from [this page](http://applied-r.com/plotting-forecast-data-objects-ggplot/) (*Custom function for plotting forecast() objects in ggplot*)

when plotting with that function I get black borders at the top and left of the entire plot as seen here:
[image]

How can I get rid of these borders?

Sorry for not writing the code here, it is too long.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with `mtcars`. Is this happening in the X11 device window, or when rendered in a report, or when copied/pasted as a bitmap, or something else?

Comment: @r2evans This is happening in the device window and when I save it as png

Comment: @r2evans this isn't a theme issue, the problem comes from the plot_fx() function, I already edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP, you indicate this is not a theme issue... but it definitely is.  If you check the linked `plot_fx()` function, it calls `theme.fx` at the end, which is declared in the link as well.  Here it is again here, with the an example made using `mtcars`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

# from the link...
theme.fxdat <- theme_gdocs() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 15),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 11),
        plot.caption = element_text(size = 9, hjust = 0, vjust = 0, colour = "grey50"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", color = "gray30"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "gray30", vjust = -1),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey95", colour = "grey75"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "grey75"),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "white"),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(colour = "white", linetype = "dotted"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = "white"),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(colour = "white", linetype = "dotted"),
        strip.background = element_rect(size = 1, fill = "white", colour = "grey75"),
        strip.text.y = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "grey75"))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + geom_point() + theme.fxdat +
  theme(rect = element_rect(color=NA))
```

I can't show you the border with an embedded graphic, as it is at the edge of the picture, as OP describes.  (it's also why we can't really see it in the OP's graphic too).

If we look at the code for `theme.fxdat`, you can see that it specifies `theme_gdocs`, which is linked to `theme_foundation`, which is linked all the way back to `theme_grey`.  I don't see a specific call to `plot.border` or `plot.background`, but it's there somewhere.

The easy fix is just addressing the theme element `plot.background`:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + geom_point() + theme.fxdat +
  theme(plot.background = element_blank())
```

That makes it go away.

Comment: Maybe I should have worded it differently but what I meant was that just calling theme.fxdat didn't show the borders but calling it with the function plot_fx() does. You were absolutely right, that fixed it. Thanks